Error in code coverage generation using Cobertura
I have a .NET code for which there are some unit test cases written.
I want to measure the code coverage using Cobertura. When I execute the command dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura , all of the unit tests are successfully passing but the XML file which is created after executing contains.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<coverage line-rate="0" branch-rate="0" version="1.9" timestamp="1724309098" lines-covered="0" lines-valid="0" branches-covered="0" branches-valid="0">
  <sources />
  <packages />
</coverage>

How do I resolve this to get the right code coverage metrics?
I tried this command dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura for executing the unit tests. The resulting XML file should contain the metrics of the code coverage.
